# Convert txt file to CSV or Excel?

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I want to convert a txt file to CSV file. I have read all post but none of them helped me because my txt file is a bit different...

I want this txt file converted to CSV file with headers `Freesapce,servername,DeviceID,size,usedspace` and with values

I want output like this:

[image: result expected]

My txt file looks like this:

```
FreeSpace  : 
Servername : sw02014
DeviceID   : 
Size       : 
UsedSpace  : 

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : A:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 40
Servername : 
DeviceID   : C:
Size       : 60
UsedSpace  : 20

FreeSpace  : 78
Servername : 
DeviceID   : D:
Size       : 100
UsedSpace  : 22

FreeSpace  : 190
Servername : 
DeviceID   : E:
Size       : 200
UsedSpace  : 10

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : G:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 
Servername : sw02111
DeviceID   : 
Size       : 
UsedSpace  : 

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : A:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 35
Servername : 
DeviceID   : C:
Size       : 60
UsedSpace  : 25

FreeSpace  : 84
Servername : 
DeviceID   : D:
Size       : 99
UsedSpace  : 15

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : I:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 
Servername : sw02014
DeviceID   : 
Size       : 
UsedSpace  : 

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : A:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 40
Servername : 
DeviceID   : C:
Size       : 60
UsedSpace  : 20

FreeSpace  : 78
Servername : 
DeviceID   : D:
Size       : 100
UsedSpace  : 22

FreeSpace  : 190
Servername : 
DeviceID   : E:
Size       : 200
UsedSpace  : 10

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : G:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 
Servername : sw02111
DeviceID   : 
Size       : 
UsedSpace  : 

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : A:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0

FreeSpace  : 35
Servername : 
DeviceID   : C:
Size       : 60
UsedSpace  : 25

FreeSpace  : 84
Servername : 
DeviceID   : D:
Size       : 99
UsedSpace  : 15

FreeSpace  : 0
Servername : 
DeviceID   : I:
Size       : 0
UsedSpace  : 0
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is a one time operation, you can simply use your favorite text editor to do a search&replace. For example with Sublime text you can search for :

```
FreeSpace  : (.*)
Servername : (.*)
DeviceID   : (.*)
Size       : (.*)
UsedSpace  : (.*)
```

And replace it by :

```
$1;$2;$3;$4;$5
```

And add manually your header. It should works fine.

If you need to do it multiple times, use you favorite script language :)